# Bootstrap 4 - Html/CSS : Sticker footer inside row-col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my content into 2 columns where the first will be used for a full height sidebar while the other will contain my navbar,content,footer.

Using Bootstrap 4.0

This is what i'm trying to do :
[image]

I'm using the sticky footer example from bootstrap 4 examples but when i add the row and columns , the footer is coming after the navbar instead of taking the whole html page length.

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
     
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">

    <div class="navbar">
      ...
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      test1
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Test</span>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using bootstrap with flex, you can use the power of flex to make a sticky footer - no need for giving it an absolute position.

**[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lax2Lkps/)**

So your html stays the same just need to add couple of layout classes. The main techique is to make .main a flex container and reposition its children in column

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

while .content block must stretch the remaining height, thus pressing the footer to the bottom, this can be achieved with simple rule:

```
.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

more on this technique [here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <html class="no-js">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
            }

            .sidenav {
                height: 100%;
                width: 160px;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 1;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: #111;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                padding-top: 20px;
            }

            .sidenav a {
                padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 25px;
                color: #818181;
                display: block;
            }

            .sidenav a:hover {
                color: #f1f1f1;
            }

            .main {
                margin-left: 160px;
                /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
                font-size: 28px;
                /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
                padding: 0px 10px;
            }

            @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
                .sidenav {
                    padding-top: 15px;
                }
                .sidenav a {
                    font-size: 18px;
                }
            }

            .footer {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="sidenav">
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                        <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-10">

                    <div class="container">
                        <h3>Tabs</h3>
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Note:</strong> content goes here</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="footer">
                        <p>Footer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="" async defer></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

check the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zmye2pth/1/

Comment: in the above code , the footer remains fixed at the bottom even if the content is greater than body height

Comment: footer should be always stick to bottom

Comment: i didnot understand what do you mean content is not going to be greater than body height

Comment: check the fiddle out you accepted an answer which does not include any main class in your answer how can you do that  despite i have given you the whole working answer SO is a site to accept correct answer not the ones with high reputation ones getting accpeted answers

Comment: i made the answer in half an hour whats wrong with it??